# bash: Make this script allow execution of php parser

Tags: php, bash, shell

Currently I start an Armagetron Server with the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

tron="/home/duke/aa/bin/armagetronad-dedicated"
var="/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/"
log="${var}console_log.txt"
userconfigdir="/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/customize/config/"
parser="/home/duke/aa/scripts/parser.php"
ladderlog="${var}ladderlog.txt"
cmds="${var}cmd.txt"

tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 $ladderlog | $parser | $tron --userconfigdir $userconfigdir --vardir $var | tee -a $log
```

This runs the server and applys the php script in $parser

However, I want to start my server like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
    screen -S $1 -X quit    # avoiding to run the same server twice
screen -dmS $1 /home/duke/aa/scripts/srv $1
```

srv:

```
screen -S $1 -X logtstamp on 
screen -S $1 -X logfile /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/logs
screen -S $1 -X log on 
while true; do  # start a loop to allow server restart if it crashes
/home/duke/aa/bin/armagetronad-dedicated --vardir /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/var  --userdatadir /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/var/customize #run the server    

    echo "###Server has crashed. Ctrl-C to cancel reboot...###"
    sleep 5

done # end the loop
```

the only problem here is I don't know how to specify a php parser to run on the server (im a noob). How would i modify the second scripts to allow this?

Comment: You can call php to run a file by running "php -f /path/to/file.php"

Comment: @fin1te would this be done in the srv script or the one with screen -dmS?

Comment: How would the php script know to affect the server being run, and not something else, like the shell?

Comment: Are you using screen as a way of keeping your server running, even if you logout from your session connection? If yes, try `man crontab`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter nah when logging out of the screen, the server should end as well. But that is very interesting, thanks

Comment: @KevninDuke : Hmmm. It's not clear to me why something you call a server is reading the tail -0n -f ... output from ladderLog. Anyway,  why can't you put all the code in your first block inside the while loop in the srv script?

Comment: thanks, I should have thought of that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put all the code in your first block inside the while loop in the srv script, i.e.

srv:

```
#!/bin/bash
tron="/home/duke/aa/bin/armagetronad-dedicated"
var="/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/"
log="${var}console_log.txt"
userconfigdir="/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/customize/config/"
parser="/home/duke/aa/scripts/parser.php"
ladderlog="${var}ladderlog.txt"
cmds="${var}cmd.txt"


screen -S $1 -X logtstamp on 
screen -S $1 -X logfile /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/logs
screen -S $1 -X log on 
while true; do  # start a loop to allow server restart if it crashes
    tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 $ladderlog | $parser | $tron --userconfigdir $userconfigdir --vardir $var | tee -a $log
    # /home/duke/aa/bin/armagetronad-dedicated --vardir /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/var  --userdatadir /home/duke/aa/servers/$1/var/customize #run the server  

    echo "###Server has crashed. Ctrl-C to cancel reboot...###"
    sleep 5

done # end the loop
```

(Does this look right?)

I hope this helps.